# Can I have two values for a constant within an NDSolve function that are dependent on the output of the NDSolve function?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a system of ODE's. One of the ODE's has a constant parameter which I want to alter between two different values depending on one of the ODE solutions.

So for example let's say that I have the following equations:

```
{
  A'[x] == -q A[x]B[x],
  B'[x] ==  q A[x]B[x] - g B[x],
  C'[x] ==  g B[x]
}
```

Now I can solve them easily using the NDSolve function when `q` and `g` are constant values. What I want to do though is vary the value of `q` so that it has one value when `B[x]` is below a certain threshold but then changes in value when `B[x]` rises above this threshold value.

I've tried using `If` statements and `Piecewise` functions outside of the `NDSolve` but I haven't managed to get it working.

Comment: That code looks a little odd.  What are `=-` and `=+`?  Anyway, welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: What initial conditions are you using? They'll be helpful for testing solutions.

Comment: Yeah sorry it wasn't mean to be code. Initially I had the 3 equations on separate lines but when I posted it they were all placed on the same line so I went back and edited it. The + signs don't need to be there. The minus sign signifies that A[x] will decrease by that amount.

Comment: I left out the initial conditions but let's say: A[0]=100, B[0]=1, C[0]=0

Comment: @Sperick You have no choice but to make `q` and `g` functions of `A[x]` and `B[x]`. They will be piecewise constant functions. You can define them using `Piecewise` or `UnitStep` functions at your preference.

Comment: Ok thanks Sasha that worked out for me. I defined g in terms of A[x] within a Piecewise above the NDSolve function.

Comment: I wouldn't use capital letters for variable names. Many of them are reserved words (C, D, E, I, N, O).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do something like what you want.  I left out the third equation, which seems superfluous.

```
Clear[f, g, s, t, x];
s[a_, b_] = Piecewise[{{a*b - b, b < 1}, {2 a*b - b, b >= 1}}];
t[a_, b_] = Piecewise[{{-a*b, b < 1}, {-2 a*b, b >= 1}}]; 
{f[x_], g[x_]} = {f[x], g[x]} /. 
  First[NDSolve[{
    f'[x] == t[f[x], g[x]],
    g'[x] == s[f[x], g[x]],
    f[0] == 10, g[0] == 1},
  {f[x], g[x]}, {x, 0, 2}]]
```